# Jasper - Pass GregorianCalendar from JSON datasource

Tags: jasper-reports

In my report I have a field `tripDate` as `java.util.GregorianCalendar`:

```
<field name="tripDate" class="java.util.GregorianCalendar"/>
```

I need to create a JSON datasource and pass this field.
I tried with different kind of solutions such as:

```
...
"tripDate": "1601897363" // value as timestamp
...
```

or as Datetime object:

```
"tripDate": {
    "date": "2020-08-12 10:10:10",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "Europe/Paris"
}
```

In both cases i get the error:

```
Unable to get value for JSON field "tripDate" of class java.util.GregorianCalendar
Field "tripDate" is of class java.util.GregorianCalendar and can not be converted.
```

There is a way to pass a `java.util.GregorianCalendar` field from JSON datasource?

Answer (score 0):

JSON/JSONQL datasources work with `java.util.Date` and its subclasses.
So you should use one of those for your textField class.

Regarding parsing of the date/time JSON string, depending on how you feed the JSON to your report you could try:

- with a dataAdapter XML file, you can set the date pattern either with Jaspersoft Studio or by hand:

  ```
  <jsonDataAdapter ...>
      ...
      <datePattern>yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss</datePattern>
      ...
  </jsonDataAdapter>
  ```
- if you don't use a data adapter and rely only on the `net.sf.jasperreports.json.source` property, you also need to set this property in your JRXML:

  ```
  <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.date.pattern" value="yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss"/>
  ```

In the same manner you could set a pattern for parsing numbers.